# Merge m3u8 playlist together

Tags: ffmpeg

i have 2 hls m3u8 files
A.m3u8  and B.m3u8
so is there a way to merge them together
so ill have 1 m3u8 file that will play same as playing a.m3u8 and b.m3u8

Answer (score 2):

Sure: [m3u8 format is simply a Unicode version of m3u](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U), which is just a text file listing the locations of files to be played.

Just open them both in a Unicode text editor, e.g. Notepad++, and concatenate them (or interleave in any order you want).

Comment: I think what the OP meant (and what is more tricky) is that different playlists may have different timestamps and settings, so just concatenating the content is not enough.